# React js with peer js runing remote stream only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webrtc, peerjs

My issue is that when I start a call for the first time I receive remote stream and the `loadMetaData()`  works fine, but when I close the call and try to call the same peerId I receive the remote stream but the `loadMetadata()`  doesn't emit any events.

MainContainer.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// @ts-ignore
import { Peer } from "peerjs";
import decodeJWT from "jwt-decode";
import callStates from "../helpers/callStates";
import { CALL_EVENTS } from "../helpers/callEvents";
import VideoBox from "./InCallView";
import OutgoingCallView from "./OutgoingCallView";
import IncomingCallView from "./IncomingCallView";
import StandbyView from "./StandbyView";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

export interface Contacts {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    peerId: string;
}

function MainContainer() {
    const [callState, setCallState] = useState(callStates.standby);
    const [contactsList, setContactsList] = useState<Contacts[]>([]);
    const [callerState, setCallerState] = useState<"receiver" | "caller">();
    const resetCallState = () => {
        setCallState(callStates.standby);
    };



    useEffect(() => {
        peer.on("connection", (conn: any) => {
            conn.on("data", async (data: { event: string }) => {
                console.log("EVENT TYPE:: ", data.event);

                if (data.event === CALL_EVENTS.CALL_REQUEST) {
                    setCallerState("receiver");
                    if (callState === callStates.standby) {
                        setCallState(callStates.incomingCall);
                    }
                }

                if (data.event === CALL_EVENTS.ANSWERED_CALL) {
                    setCallerState("caller");
                    setCallState(callStates.inCall);
                }

                if (data.event === CALL_EVENTS.REJECT_CALL) {
                    resetCallState();
                }

                if (data.event === CALL_EVENTS.END_CALL) {
                    resetCallState();
                }
            });
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [peer]);

    const handleCall = async () => {
        console.log("%c Call sent! ", "background: #222; color: #bada55; font-size: 25px");
        const conn = await peer.connect(alaaId);
        console.log({ conn });
        setCallState(callStates.outgoingCall);
        conn.on("open", () => {
            console.log("%c connection opened! ", "background: #222; color: #bada55");

            conn.send({ event: CALL_EVENTS.CALL_REQUEST });
        });
    };

    const answerCall = async () => {
        await setCallState(callStates.inCall);
        const conn = peer.connect(alaaId);
        conn.on("open", () => {
            conn.send({ event: CALL_EVENTS.ANSWERED_CALL });
        });
    };

    const rejectCall = () => {
        const conn = peer.connect(alaaId);
        conn.on("open", () => {
            conn.send({ event: CALL_EVENTS.REJECT_CALL });
            resetCallState();
        });
    };

    const endCall = () => {
        const conn = peer.connect(alaaId);
        conn.on("open", () => {
            resetCallState();
            conn.send({ event: CALL_EVENTS.END_CALL });
        });
    };

    const hangupCall = () => {
        const conn = peer.connect(alaaId);
        console.log({ conn });
        conn.on("open", () => {
            conn.send({ event: CALL_EVENTS.HANGUP_CALL });
            resetCallState();
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Box sx={{ display: callState === callStates.standby ? "none" : "block" }}>
                {callState === callStates.inCall && <VideoBox callState={callerState} peer={peer} peerId={alaaId} endCall={endCall} />}
                {callState !== callStates.standby && callState !== callStates.inCall && (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        {callState === callStates.outgoingCall && <OutgoingCallView hangupCall={hangupCall} />}
                        {callState === callStates.incomingCall && <IncomingCallView answerCall={answerCall} rejectCall={rejectCall} />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </Box>
            {callState === callStates.standby && <StandbyView handleCall={handleCall} contactsList={contactsList} />}
        </>
    );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

InCallView.tsx

```js
import { useDebugValue, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useUserMedia(constraints: any) {
    const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>();
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    useDebugValue({ error, stream });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inside main useeffect");

        let canceled = false;

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
            (stream) => {
                if (!canceled) {
                    console.log("%c inside canceled condition", "font-size:60px");
                    setStream(stream);
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                if (!canceled) {
                    setError(error);
                }
            }
        );

        return () => {
            canceled = true;
            setStream(null);
        };
    }, [constraints]);

    useEffect(
        () => () => {
            console.log("inside cancel useeffect");
            if (stream)
                stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                    track.stop();
                });
        },
        [stream]
    );

    return { error, stream };
}

export default useUserMedia;
```

useMediaStream hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function useUserMedia() {
    const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState<MediaStream>();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function enableVideoStream() {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        frameRate: { exact: 15, ideal: 15 },
                        echoCancellation: true,
                        noiseSuppression: true,
                        width: { min: 300, max: 640 },
                        height: { min: 300, max: 480 },
                    },
                });
                setMediaStream(stream);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Video error: ", err);
            }
        }

        if (!mediaStream) {
            enableVideoStream();
        } else {
            return function cleanup() {
                mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                    track.stop();
                });
            };
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [mediaStream]);
    return mediaStream;
}
```

I trie many solutions but non of them works with me

Comment: Please do not [use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for your comment i hope you has a solution for that

Comment: Well, I may not have a solution but I did retract my vote to close your question for not following the rules :) so there's that at least